# SignalR Asp.NET MVC5 User Info

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am trying to create a chat application, I want to display the Firstname of the user. However the username is their email, using

```
var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

returns their email. How can I access the Firstname property the model has and the DB has.

When they register they have to put in a first name, and the DB stores it, I just don't know how to display this in my chat from my ChatHub

Comment: Looking at the docs for Identity, it seems that only Name is held - The rest is Auth info - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. You might need to get it out of the db/local cache and send it back in the return object.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use HttpContext from inside the hub. You have Context.User.Identity.Name available inside the hub, which is recommended in SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

If somewhere in the UI you need to get the user's name and display it, then you can take it from there and send it as a parameter to your server method.

If you don't retrieve it anywhere in your client, then take it from the database inside your hub.

Note: Stop using the HttpContext global static property. Inside SignalR hubs you have access to Context, which is the one you should use.

Hope this helps! Best of luck!

Comment: Currently I'm grabbing it from the div that is holding the full name from ViewData array and passing it to the server but I feel like this isn't best practice. And Context.Identity has the username which is email not the first or last name property I added.

Comment: If you are using the standard MVC Individual User Account authentication,   the User.Identity.Name that you are going to get from any context will be the email address.

As to the HttpContext, it is never good practice to use HttpContext inside any hub.In order to access the same information in the Hub, use Context, which is special for SignalR. Think about it this way: if your client is not a web page but a desktop  or mobile application, what are you going to have inside HttpContext?

Comment: Right, I would agree with you I should use Context vs HttpContext. However this doesn't resolve the original issue of wanting grab different properties other than just the email address and identity. Like First Name, maybe Last Name, and down the line perhaps other properties that I set for users.

Comment: In your Context/HttpContext you only have the Name as the global identifier of the user across the application (in the case of the authenticatioon done in MVC - the email address). 

The only way I see , as I stated in my asnwer, is to get the information from the databse using the email address taken from Context.User.Identity.Name

Comment: That's just what I was thinking, was trying to avoid querying the DB, but I suppose that won't be too bad since it will only be done from server side and not exposed in my JS, Thanks for the help Matei_Radu!

I'm new to ASP.NET and developing a webapp on Windows in general. Just want to make sure I apply best practice, especially when it comes to security/speed.

Comment: Mark this as answered if the answer satisfies you? Best of luck!